# How to use ng-repeat in AngularJS with using array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
myApp.controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.fullname = [
        { fname: 'Mohil', age: '25', city: 'San Jose', zip:'95112' },
        { fname: 'Darshit', age: '25', city: 'San Jose', zip:'95112'},
        { fname: 'Suchita', age: '25', city: 'Santa Clara', zip:'95182'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff that can be found in just about any tutorial. Look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: I am down-voting this question as it does not show any effort from your part to answer it. As it was noted, this is basic stuff that comes in the docs and many free tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D0wZGH7zaMKHr3TQsgZI) which shows the same. All you need is,

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="name in fullname"><li ng-bind="name.fname"></li></ul>
  </body>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.fullname = [
    { fname: 'Mohil', age: '25', city: 'San Jose', zip:'95112' },
    { fname: 'Darshit', age: '25', city: 'San Jose', zip:'95112'},
    { fname: 'Suchita', age: '25', city: 'Santa Clara', zip:'95182'}
 ];
```

Comment: Well, it does depend on how you are getting access to your controller. If you are doing it the way it is shown on this answer submitted by Thomas, then his answer is fine. However, if your controller is being injected by the routing module, then you don't have to explicitly inject it on the html, just on the routing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what repeaters were designed to do, and you'd reference the properties of the object the same way you would anywhere else in JavaScript. An example that's a little bit simpler than the other given:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in fullname">
    {{ person.fname }} is {{ person.age }} years old.
  </li>
</ul>
```

What part are you struggling with?